# piping insert commands into psql tool

Tags: database, perl, postgresql, psql

I need to create a perl script that takes in 2 parameters (int runid and int iters) which will then populate a table in the postgresql database by inserting a random number with the associated runid repeatedly for iters times. I have got this simple script to work with DBI, the most used database interface for perl, however, I think this should be possible by piping insert commands into the psql tool for postgresql. However, I'm confused on how to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: DBI is just fine. Why are you trying to switch to piping your commands? There is nothing to be gained that way. (If you really *have* to: You can open a filehandle to a command like `open my $pipe, '|-', "psql", @options or die`)

Comment: You can do the inserts within a postgresql function and you would just do `select my_function(1, 100)` inside perl. If is that what you want rewrite the question

Comment: sorry but i'm trying to follow amon's suggestion, I am confused by how I would actually call the INSERT INTO command, would this be in $pipe?

Answer (score 2):

You could also just use one simple SQL command with [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html):

```
INSERT INTO tbl (runid, rnd_col)
SELECT <runid>, (random()*1000)::int
FROM   generate_series(1, <iters>)
```

This inserts `iters` rows with a random `integer` number between 0 and 1000. Adapt to your needs. Will be faster than any script your might possibly come up with.

From psql:

```sh
psql $connection_parameters -c $SQL_from_above
```